# Mysql-connector Python loss of precision

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Due to confidentiality, I will not post the table, but will provide as much detail as I can if someone needs more information.

I am doing a "SELECT AVG(result)"  from a table and when I use this query on mysql workbench, the result is something like 99.78999999999999. However when I try to use mysql connector in python, as soon as I do a

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

and I check the results, the value is 99.79. It rounds it by itself and I'm not sure why.

**EDIT**

99.7, 99.9, 99.8, 99.85, 99.6, 99.85, 99.85, 99.75, 99.8, 99.8 Which averages to 99.78999999999999 in mysql workbench but 99.79 in python mysql-connector

Comment: What is the type of result in the database?

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the reply. I am performing an AVG operation on a column that is of DOUBLE type so I'm assuming the select AVG(result) will also result in double?

Comment: and if you convert the result into a text ..?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I could try that, but why would I convert to text? All my results are double values.

Comment: I just want to see how is the behavior

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Shoot. Unfortunately I do not have permission to change datatype. Sorry! Any other suggestions?

Comment: 92.78999999999999 is the single precision representation of the double 92.79. So somehow calculation is done in single precision.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I figured that much, but don't quite understand why it is happening.

Comment: try with an CAST DECIMAL

Comment: @Daniel How did you get that it's the single precision representation of the double 92.79? I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Well the problem is, like I said, it shows up correctly in mysql workbench, but when I try to print out the value in python with mysql connector, it is rounding the value to two decimal places.

Comment: @rominoushana Wait, are you saying `92.78999999999999` is correct? What numbers do you have such that their average is that?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes it is correct. When I retrieve the average value in python, I want to be able to get the same value that I get in mysql workbench which is 92.78999999999. Instead I'm getting a rounded of value. I am averaging numbers that are like 7 or 8 significant digits

Comment: @rominoushana Can you share the numbers? Might provide some insight.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I would love to, but there are just too many numbers to share. However, just a note, I think your missing the point of the question. It is not that the average is wrong. It is that python mysql connector is rounding off the average and I'm losing precision.If you still think the numbers are necessary, then I will see the best way to post them

Comment: I don't see how we can realistically expect to solve this when we have essentially no information to work with.

Comment: @AMC I apologize. Here are the results:

99.7, 99.9, 99.8, 99.85, 99.6, 99.85, 99.85, 99.75, 99.8, 99.8 

Which averages to 99.78999999999999 in mysql workbench but 99.79 in python mysql-connector. 

Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @rominoushana So you prefer the wrong value?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm not sure why you are saying it is the wrong value? It's not wrong. It just had more precision

Comment: @rominoushana The average of those numbers is 99.79, not 99.78999999999999.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Oh. Then why is mysql workbench giving me that number. So mysql workbench is giving a wrong value?

Comment: @rominoushana My point was that the number of potential causes is enormous, and we have no way of examining them ourselves. For all we know this is happening because it's Thursday, you're using Newfoundland Standard Time, and your computer's keyboard language is set to esperanto.

Comment: @rominoushana https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1672429

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thank you. I guess that solves it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StefanPochmann mentions in the comments, the average output that mysql workbench is incorrect. Here is an explanation on why: [stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1672429](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1672429)